# IntelliJ Enter as shortcut key

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Strange problem.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html

I think this pretty clearly says that i should use mouse, since Enter is taken as shortcut key if pressed.
However, i do want to bind Enter to jump to source, but if i press either enter on keyboard, this will only close the dialog.. shortcut still at F4

on Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you press Enter, it triggers the "OK" button & close the dialog, you should click on the plus sign on the right then choose some special keys which cannot be pressed directly
 (ambiguous with dialog interaction)

[image]

Comment: I've seem to become blind to these + marks, thanks!

Comment: Also, i do understand that Enter will usually close dialog boxes, however on help page it says "It is important that you use the mouse pointer because pressing Enter while in the Keyboard Shortcut dialog is treated as a key combination that you want to use as a shortcut. " Which seems to be just wrong info

Comment: No, Enter does not really close, Enter activates the current active button (blue grow button), and in this case, it activates the OK button that closes & saves the current value. You can use Tab so switch active button and Enter to simulate "click" on that one